# How can I search for the database and return the entire array in one go?

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I have a select state `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE age = 21 LIMIT 10` in my php script. Right now, I have to loop through the rows to keep getting new rows of data. How can I do it, so it turns me the entire data in `O(1)` time complexity? Right now I have a while loop which makes it `O(n)`.

```
function search($stmt, $age) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users
            WHERE age = ?
            LIMIT 10";
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $age);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        $outfitArray = [];
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $searchResults[] = $row;
        }

        return $searchResults;
    }
}
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
if($conn != false) $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

print_r(search($stmt, 21));
```

---

My second question is, what select statement do I use to see put an offset. So if I get 50 results, how can I get the results that are the 40th - 50th result.

---

My third question is, how can I get the number of results in a search **without** putting all the results into an array or using a loop? Then using something like `count()` to see how many items there are.

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: Also, as things tend to get older, this query's only good for, at most, one year

Comment: @Strawberry what do u mean it gets old? Whats something that stays relevant all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all the data in one pass, you can use [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) e.g.

```
$searchResults = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Note you need to specify `MYSQLI_ASSOC` as the default for this function is `MYSQLI_NUM`.

To get rows e.g. from 41-50 you would use an offset with your [limit clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

```
LIMIT 40, 10
```

Note that using `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY` is meaningless as there is no guarantee of the ordering of rows and you may get a different result each time you execute the query. You may want to order by the `id`, or the user's name or something similar.

To get the number of the results in a search, change the query to use [`COUNT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count):

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_results FROM Users WHERE age = ?";
```